# Change body onclick to button Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this script that will open popup when click any body.
how to change instead body click it should be button click or link click before the popup appear? Do i need to create button of anything. code much appreciate.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var win = window.open('http://google.com', "popup", 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
if (!win){
//    alert("failed for most browsers");
    document.body.onclick = function () {
         window.open('http://google.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
    };
}else {
    var thisdoc = document;
    //Is it Chrome?
    if(/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ((win.innerHeight > 0) == false){
//                alert("failed for chrome");
                  thisdoc.body.onclick = function () {
                      window.open('http://google.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
                  };
             }
        }, 100);
    }else{
       win.onload = function() {
            if ((win.innerHeight > 0) == false){
//                alert("failed for others");
                  thisdoc.body.onclick = function () {
                     window.open('http://google.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
                  };
            }
       };
    }
}
</script>
```

JS : FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/ayiem999/678Ru/ ( WITH BUTTON CREATE. PLEASE PLAY)

**MY ANSWER FOR THIS QUESTION FOR REFERENCE :**

```
<button id="3" onclick="reply_click(this.id)">B3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
window.open('http://google.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to handle a button click without a button?

Comment: right now when i click any page the popup will appear.. i do not want that. i want it should be a button click or link click not page body click

Comment: put the `.onclick = function(){}` on a button element instead of body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OnClick without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854772/onclick-without-jquery)

Comment: no .. i just check .. i want this to be a button not body  thisdoc.body.onclick = function () <-- how to change to button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your link or button has an ID of `myButton` then it's

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function () {
     window.open('http://google.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
};
```

This is without jQuery as it isn't needed. If you want to use it instead then it's

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function(){
    window.open('http://google.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=650, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pfj8B/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a button in your page like

```
<button id="myButton">My Button</button>
```

then

```
document.body.onclick = function () {
```

becomes

```
$('#myButton').click(function() { ... });
```