# Why does my javascript var value keep reseting?

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have navigation with 3 links.

When i click each link i want it to hide other elements and display itself.

After i click on my link it does what its supposed to do but it resets and shows everything after few seconds.

**Heres link to code pen just so you can see what keeps happening.**

https://codepen.io/necapereca/pen/zRwZbz

```
function show(choice){
  var user=choice;

  if ( user == 1) {
        document.getElementById('one').style = "display:block";
        document.getElementById('two').style ="display:none";
        document.getElementById('three').style ="display:none";
      }

      else if ( user == 2) {
        document.getElementById('one').style = "display:none";
        document.getElementById('two').style ="display:block";
        document.getElementById('three').style ="display:none";
      }

      else if ( user == 3) {
        document.getElementById('one').style = "display:none";
        document.getElementById('two').style ="display:none";
        document.getElementById('three').style ="display:block";
      }    
}
```

Comment: You used a `<a>` tag, so the page is reloading. Don't use `<a>` when what you want is just something clickable to trigger JavaScript; use `<button type=button>` and style it the way you want it to look.

Comment: Just make `href=""` as `href="#"` and retrun false at the end of the function

Comment: i put <a href="#"></a> and it works thanks

Comment: @neca I [modified your example in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48733673/344029) to use a `button` instead which avoids the problem completely. I also improved a few things to keep everything really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You var is not resetting, actually the page is reloading. You can avoid that in many different ways:

### event.preventDefault()

Pass the `event` global variable to your click function and call `event.preventDefault()`, this is going to stop the default behavior of clicking `a` link.

```js
function show(event, choice){
  event.preventDefault();
  var user=choice;
  
  if ( user == 1) {
        document.getElementById('one').style = "display:block";
        document.getElementById('two').style ="display:none";
        document.getElementById('three').style ="display:none";
      }
  
      else if ( user == 2) {
        document.getElementById('one').style = "display:none";
        document.getElementById('two').style ="display:block";
        document.getElementById('three').style ="display:none";
      }
  
      else if ( user == 3) {
        document.getElementById('one').style = "display:none";
        document.getElementById('two').style ="display:none";
        document.getElementById('three').style ="display:block";
      }    
}
```

```css
.div1{
  background-color:red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
.div2{
  background-color:blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
.div3{
  background-color:green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="" onclick="show(event, 1)">HOME</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="" onclick="show(event, 2)">ABOUT ME</a>       
<a class="nav-link" href="" onclick="show(event,3)">CONTACT</a>
<div class="div1" id="one"></div>
<div class="div2" id="two"></div>
<div class="div3" id="three"></div>
```

### add a #hash link on your `a` tag

This will navigate to `#one` but it will not reload the page.

```
<a href="#one">
```

### change your `a` tag to a `button` tag

Buttons don't navigate away from the page by default.

Answer (score 0):

You must give your href an hash, else you'll navigate to a said url. If no url provided it will refresh the current url which is what is happening.
Just add something like  `#(something)`. See below ! Or use a button instead of an `a` tag

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#1" onclick="show(1)">HOME</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#2" onclick="show(2)">ABOUT ME</a>       
<a class="nav-link" href="#3" onclick="show(3)">CONTACT</a>
<div class="div1" id="one"></div>
<div class="div2" id="two"></div>
<div class="div3" id="three"></div>
```

Working forked pen https://codepen.io/wilomgfx/pen/vdmmKP

Comment: Using a  hash (`#`) will work, but instead of that the default behaviour of the event should be prevented. Using a hash might result in nwanted scrolls to the top or to an element with that ` id` .

Answer (score 0):

It's your html. The href needs either a hash:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="show(1)">HOME</a>
```

Or put:

```
  <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show(1)">HOME</a>
```

But the best thing to do is avoid the problem and [use a stylised `<button>` tag instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525002/344029):

```js
var divs = ["one", "two", "three"];
divs.forEach(function(id){
    document.getElementById('btn-'+id).onclick = function() {
        show(id);
    };
});

function show(id){
    divs.forEach(function(id){
        document.getElementById(id).style = "display:none";
    });
                 
    document.getElementById(id).style = "display:block";
}
```

```css
.div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {  background-color:red; }
.div2 {  background-color:blue; }
.div3 {  background-color:green; }

button.link {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#00f;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<button class="link" id="btn-one">HOME</button>
<button class="link" id="btn-two">ABOUT ME</button>       
<button class="link" id="btn-three">CONTACT</button>
<div class="div div1" id="one"></div>
<div class="div div2" id="two"></div>
<div class="div div3" id="three"></div>
```

Run the code snippet to see it in action, and here's [the code in an updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZmaee).

- I used a simple way to [attach click events without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/854819/344029).
- When you click a 'link', all divs are hidden then the correct one is shown.
- I also simplified the CSS

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have `href=""` on your link and therefore navigation occurs. One of the solutions will be to `return false` from your function and tweak HTML to `onclick="return show.."`.

See complete **HTML**

```
<a class="nav-link" href="" onclick="return show(1)">HOME</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="" onclick="return show(2)">ABOUT ME</a>       
<a class="nav-link" href="" onclick="return show(3)">CONTACT</a>
<div class="div1" id="one"></div>
<div class="div2" id="two"></div>
<div class="div3" id="three"></div>
```

and **Javascript**

```
function show(choice){
  var user=choice;

  if ( user == 1) {
        document.getElementById('one').style = "display:block";
        document.getElementById('two').style ="display:none";
        document.getElementById('three').style ="display:none";
      }

      else if ( user == 2) {
        document.getElementById('one').style = "display:none";
        document.getElementById('two').style ="display:block";
        document.getElementById('three').style ="display:none";
      }

      else if ( user == 3) {
        document.getElementById('one').style = "display:none";
        document.getElementById('two').style ="display:none";
        document.getElementById('three').style ="display:block";
      }    

  return false;
}
```

Another solution will be to simply remove `href=""` from your links, but you will lose their 'link' styling.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the empty href or replace it with `href="#!"`
This will prevent the page from reloading.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `show` function is not the problem but how you are calling it. The right way would be using a button:

```
<button onclick = "show(1)"> Show 1 </button>
```

However while that fix is easy, you could greatly reduce your code by looping over your elements. Then you can show it if the elements index matches the index to show, otherwise you can hide it:

```
 function show(index){
   const ids = ["one", "two", "three"];

   for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
      document.getElementById(ids[i])
         .style.display = index - 1 === i ? "block" : "none";
}
```